# Eliminar espacios en blanco de una variable tipo string en php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Como están?...Tengo un problema que no logro resolver, necesito registrar en una base de datos en un campo el resultado que me arroja una variable, pero debo registrarlo todo de seguido, el dato debe quedar de la siguiente forma ejemplo:  01:00,02:00,03;00..... estos datos los tomo de un array el cual logro sacarlos con un foreach,  `$horario=array(0=>array(0=>"00:00,"), 1=>array(1=>"01:00,"),  2=>array(2=>"02:00,"), 3=>array(3=>"03:00,"),`

hasta allí no hay problema, con esta constante,($contenido.= $status.PHP_EOL;) yo logro pasar todos los registros sin inconveniente, ósea todo queda guardado en la variable  $contenido.

El problema es cuando voy a registrar en la base de datos o los quiero imprimir en pantalla los dato me quedan así: 01:00, 02:00, 03;00 con un espacio después de cada coma, he tratado de eliminar esos espacios  con varias funciones y siguen saliendo con ese espacio, entonces cuando se registra en el campo no me registra en una sola fila o linea, si no que se van registrando hacia abajo, ósea un dato encima del otro, esto por el espacio que queda después de cada coma.

Ósea hacia abajo, esto ocurre por el espacio, cuando debería registrar de esta forma: 01:00,02:00, 03;00,
en una sola fila, he intentado con varias funciones PHP que sirven para eliminar espacios como por ejemplo, con trim() - str_replace() y otras formas y no logro, si me pueden ayudar por favor, coloco el código para tener una idea, muchas gracias.

````
                               1=>array(1=>"01:00,"), 
                               2=>array(2=>"02:00,"),
                               3=>array(3=>"03:00,"),
                               4=>array(4=>"04:00,"),
                               5=>array(5=>"05:00,"),
                               6=>array(6=>"06:00,"),
                               7=>array(7=>"07:00,"),
                               8=>array(8=>"08:00,"),
                               9=>array(9=>"09:00,"),
                              10=>array(10=>"10:00,"),
                              11=>array(11=>"11:00,"),
                              12=>array(12=>"12:00,"), 
                              13=>array(13=>"13:00"),
                              14=>array(14=>"14:00"),
                              15=>array(15=>"15:00"),
                              16=>array(16=>"16:00"),
                              17=>array(17=>"17:00"),
                              18=>array(18=>"18:00"),
                              19=>array(19=>"19:00"),
                              20=>array(20=>"20:00"),
                              21=>array(21=>"21:00"),
                              22=>array(22=>"22:00"), 
                              23=>array(23=>"23:00"));  
     


  $nuevoFormato = '';
  $inicio = $lunesdesde;
  $fin    = $luneshasta;

  foreach($horario as $grupo) {
  foreach($grupo as $status) {
     $nuevoFormato = $status;
     
     if($nuevoFormato >= $inicio && $nuevoFormato <= $fin) {
      

         $contenido.= $status.PHP_EOL;// aqui logro dejar los datos que necesito en la variable 
        contenido
         
   
             }// fin del if
    }// fin del foreach
  }// fin del foreach 

      $contenido;
        
        
         $cambiostatus="UPDATE HORARIO SET status=:statu WHERE cuenta=:cuent ";
        
        $resultadostatus=$conexi->prepare($cambiostatus);
        
        $resultadostatus->execute(array( ":cuent"=>$registro['cuenta'] ,
        ":statu"=>$contenido  )); ```



Recuerden todo funciona perfecto, los datos se registran bien pero con esos espacios entonces se registran en forma de  columna y necesito es que el registro quede en una sola linea o fila.

Gracias!! 

 





[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAsX9.jpg
````

Comment: Parece que lo que buscas es eliminar "espacio blanco", PHP tiene un método llamado ```trim()``` https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php el cuál puede eliminar cualquier espacio de ese tipo y según entiendo eso es lo que buscas hacer. Puedes especificar también el lado, si quieres cortar del lado derecho o izquierdo con ```ltrim()``` ```rtrim()``` https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_trim.asp

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto el problema, lo publico para si alguien da con este inconveniente pueda resolverlo, con la constante `PHP_EOL` logre colocar todos los datos en una sola variable, que salían del `foreach`, entonces lo que pasaba es que el espacio lo generaba el `foreach` en cada vuelta, porque quedaba como salto de linea, lo resolví así:

```
$contenido1 = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", "", $contenido);
```

Eliminando los saltos de linea y si puedes apreciar las comillas juntas para que no quedara nada de espacios entre los datos.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contenidoSinEspacios = str_replace(" ","", $contenido)
```

Comment: Si, ya este código lo aplique pero no funciona, sigue saliendo el espacio

Comment: Yo lo acabo de comprobar y me funciona.

Comment: Y por qué no quitas el PHP_EOL? Al final eso se traduce (según s.o.) en \n o en \r\n... No tiene sentido añadirlo para luego querer quitarlo... No?

Comment: Si quito el PHP_EOL como esta dentro de foreach deja como resultado el ultimo valor, ósea no guarda todos los datos en la variable $contenido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con preg_replace de esta forma:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```